# Can you call a human 'common' or 'ordinary' if you expected him previously to have some unusual features?

Tags: word-choice

Imagine you meet someone and expected him too look not like other men. For example, to have a tail or feathers or celtic tattoos all over the face. And when you see him, he looks quite like ***ordinary*** / ***common*** people.

Take into account, that I do NOT want to say that he is bland and uninteresting, just that he has not unusual features. He may have a vivid appearance.

*There stood a quite **common**, lively boy.*

If there are better options, I would like to hear them too.

Comment: "stand common" is not idiomatic at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, to my knowledge every word which means "not very different from most people/the average person" also has a somewhat negative connotation: they suggest the person is mediocre or uninteresting.

Your best options are probably **ordinary**, or **normal**. *Ordinary* is more precise, because it specifically means "having no unusual features." *Normal* is more general, so you might consider saying he was "normal looking" to clarify. "Ordinary looking" is also a common phrase. You might also want to follow up this description by clarifying that he wasn't *bland* (unless you want to suggest that)--just that he didn't have whatever exceptional feature you expect. In novels this is a common construction. You often hear things like "I went into the room terrified, but in the end he seemed quite ordinary. Not to say he was boring to look at--his eyes were wide and very blue, and [...]"

Other options and their problems include:

> **Common**: has a strongly negative connotation, especially when applied to a person. It suggests they are cheap or uninteresting. It can also mean 'lower-class', and so it can sound snooty unless used carefully. 
> **Regular**: not usually applied to people, and even then doesn't suggest 'unexceptional', merely 'uniform' 
> **Conventional**: technically this works, though it usually refers to a person's interests or manners. A 'conventional' person might be someone who follows mainstream trends, or does not wear interesting clothes.
> **Unexceptional**: fine literally, but strongly suggests a lack of intelligence or skill.

And, just to nitpick, the sentence you provide needs an article and another comma

> There stood (a/the) quiet, common, lively boy.

and the construction is somewhat old-fashioned (if you are trying to say that there is a quiet, common, lively boy standing). It's not unusual, but it is literary.

Comment: Oh, that was a typo. I meant 'There stood quite common, lively boy.' But thanks for the article, I needed it. Also I meant bland or something close to that.

And great answer. I think, normal looking is just what I need.

Comment: The thing is, I *am* writing it down into a story. Is it okay then or too literary? I am trying to say that there is a quite normal looking, lively boy standing, as you say. Better ways to say that?

Comment: @Tuffling_Tony I don't think there's anything wrong with it in the context of a story. Nothing wrong with being literary in literature :) One way to make it slightly more standard might be to include where he's standing, for example "Near the corner  stood a quite normal looking, lively boy." To my ear that sounds perfectly natural. Happy writing!